# How to Create a feedback form in HTML Email?

Tags: html, web, outlook

I want to create a Html Email with an Feedback form.
I already have working html code that is displayed correctly in things like gmail outlook web etc.

My problem is that every field that shows an input is not displayed correctly in Outlook 2003/07/10/13

Is there a way to make fields work in these and if not is there a way to check in my html file if the email is shown in one of the above mentioned outlook versions so i can replace the form with a link?

Thanks in Advance

This is how it looks in Outlook Online:
[image: This is how it looks in Outlook online]

This is how it looks in Outlook 2010:

[image: This is how it looks in Outlook 2010]

Comment: You are seeing this after sending email? What are you trying to achieve? is it something you will send an email with a form? please explain

Comment: I want to send the form inside an email to customers so they can give me feedback. Most Email Clients show the html correctly like the first screenshot example. But older Outlook versions do not show input fields. So I either want to now if its possible to show html input fields in outlook or if its possible to check inside the email if its opened in outlook

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/forms-in-email/ this may help you understand what is possible in email.